# Prevent user from "grabbing and dragging" scroll bar handle?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, scrollbar

For lack of a better way to describe it - there are 3 ways to manipulate a live scroll bar in application: clicking the arrows, clicking above/below the handle (that goes up and down), and clicking and dragging the handle itself.

When the user clicks and drags the handle on my `DataGridView` with a custom class, it causes a painting issue where the gridlines will disappear when you scroll down, then back up. This doesn't happen when using the other two methods of scrolling.

I can't seem to figure out a solution to the painting problem, so it seems the scroll bar might be easier to solve the problem. Is it possible to disable that grab and drag?

Comment: You forgot the mousewheel ;) on a more serious note, are you custom painting the datagridview?

Comment: First, mousewheel doesn't scroll because the datagridview is never actually selected, per se. Basically, whenever you click on it, it pops up another panel to do other stuff. Second point: I'm not actually custom painting it, that is no overrides on the standard. But I am overriding the "AdjustCellBorderStyle" properties.